# Extract multiple values from unformated text

Tags: go, text, extract

My question is how to extract the value following `Count:`, `Temp:`, `Total:`, `Used:` from this multi-line text in go.

```
Welcome, user [User CP]   [Count: 1,014,747.1] [some] [Ohter: 0]

Temp:  14.231  Total:  10.0 TB Used:  964.57 GB  On line:  2  0 Traffic Count: 1995




10 (0 New)   0
```

So I can get these values `1,014,747.1`, `14.231`, `10.0TB`, `964.57GB` then assign to a go struct like

```golang
struct {
    Count float64
    Temp  float64
    Total string
    Used  string
}
```

I've tried with regexp but it result in I need to write four regxp and run four times with the same text to extract these value one by one. Why I need run 4 times is clear because I write 4 regxp to extract the for values.

```
var count = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(Count:\s*(\d+([\,]\d+)*([\.]\d+)))`)
var temp = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(Temp:\s*(\d+[\.]?\d*))`)
var total = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(Total:\s*(\d+\.?\d*\s\w\w))`)
var used = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(Used:\s*(\d+\.?\d*\s\w\w))`)

// run these regexp to get values
```

I've tried using one regexp, but the match result contain a lot of emtpy elements I cant get the value by a fixed index.

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(Count:\s*(\d+([\,]\d+)*([\.]\d+)))|(Temp:\s*(\d+[\.]?\d*))|(Total:\s*(\d+\.?\d*\s\w\w))|(Used:\s*(\d+\.?\d*\s\w\w))`)
    var str = `Welcome, user [User CP]   [Count: 1,014,747.1] [some] [Ohter: 0]

Temp:  14.231  Total:  10.0 TB Used:  964.57 GB  On line:  2  0 Traffic Count: 1995




10 (0 New)   0`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}
```

the result is, there some different amount of empty elements in the result so I can't get the value via a fix index.

```
[Count: 1,014,747.1 Count: 1,014,747.1 1,014,747.1 ,747 .1      ] found at index 0
[Temp:  14.231     Temp:  14.231 14.231    ] found at index 1
[Total:  10.0 TB       Total:  10.0 TB 10.0 TB  ] found at index 2
[Used:  964.57 GB         Used:  964.57 GB 964.57 GB] found at index 3
```

`1,014,747.1` at index 2, `14.231` at index 6, `10.0 TB` at index 8, `964.57 GB` at index 10. So I can't get the value by using a fixed index.
more clear subgroup result at https://regex101.com/r/jenOHn/3, the match information shows the problem.

So is there a more elegant way to extract these values? The order of the values may vary and it might have some extra word (or miss some word) in between the text so extract by count length is not possible.

I've thought about using a finite state machine but can't figure how to implement one and I also not sure its a right way to do so.

Comment: "I've tried with regxp but it result in I need to write four regxp and run four times with the same text to extract these value one by one." - you should be able to scan each line only once. Please show the code you used and had trouble with.

Comment: I extract every value with a specific regxp. So I just write 4 regxp to extract the 4 values. Thus runs 4 times. @Adrian

Comment: And I'm saying you don't need to do that, but we'd still need to see the actual code.

Comment: Oh I get it, I've updated the code. @Adrian

Comment: The quoted code executes the regex once and iterates through the results, so I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Yes it is. But the problem is the match result makes it unuseable, and foce me to use 4 different regxp above the quoed code, there a lot of empty element in the result, so I cant pick the value with a index, please see the regex101 link below, check the match information,  the output issue of match 1~4 about why I need write the redundant regxp. My question is how to extract the values from the text with a proper way. @Adrian

Comment: There are four regxp in the **third** code block, I omited the execution of them. @Adrian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211096/discussion-between-li-jinyao-and-adrian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a ton of capturing groups in there that you aren't actually trying to capture, and a lot of unnecessarily specified stuff, and a missing `s` flag. I've cleaned up the expression and it works: https://play.golang.org/p/D9WxFCYQ8s0

```
(?ms)Count:\s*([0-9,.]+).*Temp:\s*([0-9.]+).*Total:\s*([0-9.]+).*Used:\s*([0-9.]+)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need the unit. So I modify the Total and Used to `Total:\s*([0-9.]+\s*\w{2}).*Used:\s*([0-9.]+\s*\w{2})`